# Spring Batch Partition Step exhaust all taskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch for many jobs running at same time.

I configured taskExecutor `corePoolSize=40`,
and jobs are read from splitted flat files and write into Database.

The problem is if splitted files are over the `corePoolSize`(e,g file count >= 40), then other jobs running same time are got stuck, because one partition step is using entire taskExecutor.

I'm using `MultiResourcePartitioner` and `FlatFileItemReader`.

To solve this problem, i tried to extends `MultiResourcePartitioner` to use grid size like below and use `MultiResourceItemReader` to archive like this.

```
// if file count is 8 and gridsize is 2 then  
partition-0 : [file0, ..., file3]
partition-1 : [file4, ..., file7]
```

and, code like below

```
@Override
protected Map<String, ExecutionContext> createPartitionMap(String serviceCode, String targetPath, int gridSize) {

    Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionMap = new HashMap<>(gridSize);

    File inputFile = new File(targetPath);
    Collection<File> files;
    if (inputFile.isDirectory()) {
        files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(targetPath), null, true);
    } else {
        files = new ArrayList<>();
        files.add(inputFile);
    }

    int fileCount = files.size();
    int fileIndex = 0;

    for (File file : files) {

        int mapIndex = fileIndex % gridSize;
        String partitionKey = String.format("partition-%d", mapIndex);

        ExecutionContext context;
        if (partitionMap.containsKey(partitionKey)) {
            context = partitionMap.get(partitionKey);
        } else {
            context = new ExecutionContext();
            partitionMap.put(partitionKey, context);
        }

        List<Resource> resources;
        if (context.containsKey(BatchJobConfig.PARAM_FILE_RESOURCE)) {
            resources = (List<Resource>) context.get(BatchJobConfig.PARAM_FILE_RESOURCE);
        } else {
            resources = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        resources.add(new FileSystemResource(file.getPath()));
        context.put(BatchJobConfig.PARAM_FILE_RESOURCE, resources);

        fileIndex++;
    }

    logger.info(partitionMap.toString());

    return partitionMap;
}
```

but it's not working because using `MultiResourceItemReader` on multi threads seems not thread safe.

So i want each step(or job) to be limited to use pool count or assign taskExecutor to each jobs differently.

How can i solve that situation?

Comment: Why don't you just configure a thread pool specifically for that job?

Comment: @MichaelMinella even though i increment `corePoolSize` over 100, if file count >= 100 then it will occur same problem..
you mean specify different `taskExecutor` to each job?

Comment: Yes, I mean a separate `taskExecutor` bean per job.

Comment: @MichaelMinella Thank you, it seems to be solved. 
i just worried about if many jobs are running at same time then so many taskExecutor as jobs count will created, so "will it make some problems?" 
i just changed `taskExecutor` bean type to `prototype` from `singleton`.
i should test more to check any problem.